# Generate the conference badge

Tags: pdf-format

I have a list of about 50 conference attendees with 3 columns (First name, Last name, University). I would like to use *Mathematica* to generate the conference badge for each people. The badge dimension is about 4"x3" (for the normal name badges holders). The logo of the conference could be inserted at the top right corner of the badges.
Could someone help me the code to generate these badges with nice border?
Many thanks...[image]

Comment: Surely you've been able to make some headway on your own? Please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make a designer badge using some graphics software like Adobe Illustrator or Corel Draw, import it as an image and use as background.

Since you already have the name list you can easily import them and place anywhere on the badge.

As an example, I use the badge you post here (with a little crappy edit).

[image]

```
badge = Import["8cVj2.jpg"]


name={{"A1","B1","C1"},{"A2","B2","C2"},{"A3","B3","C3"}};
cand=Length[name]  (*number of candidate*)
name//TableForm

fullname[i_] := StringJoin[name[[i, 1]], "  ", name[[i, 2]], "  ", name[[i, 3]]]
(*combine the first middle and last name from the list*)

Table[Show[badge, Graphics[{Text[Style[fullname[i], 20, Bold, Italic], {300, 450}]}], ImageSize -> 200], {i, cand}]
```

you can change the `Style`, text position, `ImageSize` as you like.
[image]

> Background with Mathematica

Here is a simple example of a background consisting of random disks.

```
head = Style["Conference",30,Bold];
name=  Style["Mr. A. B. Cdef",25,Bold];
affl=  Style["XYZ University",25,Bold];

width=5;
ratio=4/6;
frame={Black,Thickness[0.1]}
image=Graphics[Table[{RGBColor[RandomReal[{0,1},3]],Opacity[RandomReal[]],Disk[RandomReal[{-2,2}width,2],RandomReal[{0.3,2}]]},{n,500}],PlotRange->{{-1,1}width,{-1,1}width/ratio}];

Show[image,Graphics[{Text[head,{0,.9width}],Text[name,{0,.3width}],Text[affl,{0,-.1width}]}],Frame->True,FrameTicks->False,FrameStyle->Directive[frame]]
```

[image]

Now it is always possible to use a `Plot3D` or `DensityPlot` or may be nice fractal for your badge. The improvement depends on your imagination.

Comment: thank you... I prefer generating the more elegant badges with Mathematica.

Comment: Hi @DaoTRINH . I am not sure what do you mean by creating elegant badges with mathematica. You can make a nice 3d plot of some function from your field and use it as background. Sometime people use a density plot of their spectroscopy data as background. If you know a good function or have some data you can create the image and use it. You can consult any book on fractal for a nice image. I'm sorry I can't be of any more help.  I post one random pattern.